# Hide table row with javascript (NO jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have this table element called *semana2* in `<tr>` tag. How can I hide/show using only javascript (no jQuery)

I try this and won't work:
    document.getElementById('semana2').style.visibility = false;

Comment: use `style.visibility = hidden` instead of `style.visibility = false;`

Comment: `false` is not a valid value for `visibility`. Try `hidden` instead. But you might be looking for `display:none` rather than that...

Comment: `"hidden"`, not `hidden`, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 document.getElementById('semana2').style.display = "none";
```

Visibility is also ok but you have to use it like:

```
document.getElementById('semana2').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Just a note though, if you use visibility "hidden" the box of your element will still be rendered. I.e.: if you have a div 20x20 and apply `visibility = "hidden";` to it, you will end up with a 20x20 empty square. While if you set `display = "none";` then it will be like nothing is there at all.

Comment: funny how visibility mantains the row but hide the text, and display method hide the intire row

Comment: `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` are not interchangable - they have different behaviours. @Carlos it's not funny - it's just the CSS spec. Also, visibility has been supported in every major browser for ages - there are no compatibility problems. It even works in IE __4__.

Answer (score 6):

`false` isn't a valid value for the `visibility` property.

You should use one of these options:

- `myElement.style.display = "none"` (hide, and don't show an empty space)
- `myElement.style.visibility = "hidden"` or `myElement.style.opacity = 0` (hide, but show an empty space where the element would be).

`opacity` has the nice property that it can be animated with a [CSS transition](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/), although you should be aware of [limited compatibility with IE < 9](http://caniuse.com/css-opacity).

Incidentally, The valid values for `visibility` are `visible | hidden | collapse`  - See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).